System.AggregateException : (The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: RevealWebApplicationFixture
I am using IClassFixture in my xunit test.
I am not sure why I am getting this error even though I have mocked all the dependencies used in the controller.
This is my test class
[Collection("UserCamerasRelatedEndpointsCollection")]
public class GetControlUnitsGroupedByVehicleTests : IClassFixture<RevealWebApplicationFixture>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly Fixture _fixture;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly Mock<IUserContext> _mockUserContext;
    private readonly Mock<IControlUnitRepository> _mockControlUnitRepository;
    private readonly Mock<IControlUnitMapper> _mockControlUnitMapper;
    private readonly Mock<ILogger<UserCamerasController>> _mockUserCamerasControllerLogger;

    private const string CameraListApiUrl = "/v1/user-cameras/camera-list-page";

    public GetControlUnitsGroupedByVehicleTests(RevealWebApplicationFixture revealWebApplicationFixture)
    {
        _fixture = revealWebApplicationFixture.Fixture;
        _httpClient = revealWebApplicationFixture.HttpClient;
        _mockUserContext = revealWebApplicationFixture.MockUserContext;
        _mockControlUnitRepository = revealWebApplicationFixture.MockControlUnitRepository;
        _mockControlUnitMapper = revealWebApplicationFixture.MockControlUnitMapper;
        _mockUserCamerasControllerLogger = revealWebApplicationFixture.MockLogger;
   
    }



[Fact]
public async Task ControlUnitsByAccountId_ShouldReturnBadRequestForInvalidOffset()
{
    // arrange
    const string urlWithInvalidOffset = $"{CameraListApiUrl}?Offset=-1";

    // act
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(urlWithInvalidOffset);

    // assert
    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response.StatusCode);
    }
}

This is my Fixture and it inherits from another one
public class RevealWebApplicationFixture : WebApplicationFixture, IDisposable
{
    public Mock<IControlUnitRepository> MockControlUnitRepository { get; }
    public Mock<IControlUnitMapper> MockControlUnitMapper { get; }
    public Mock<IUserContext> MockUserContext { get; }
    public Mock<ILogger<UserCamerasController>> MockLogger { get; }


    public RevealWebApplicationFixture()
    {
        MockControlUnitRepository = new Mock<IControlUnitRepository>();
        MockControlUnitMapper = new Mock<IControlUnitMapper>();
        MockUserContext = new Mock<IUserContext>();
        MockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<UserCamerasController>>();
        Fixture = new Fixture();
        WebAppFactory = GetWebApplicationFactory();
        HttpClient = WebAppFactory.CreateClient();
    }
}

This is the other fixture which build the Host.
The error is happening in this class when I am building the WebHost.
    public abstract class WebApplicationFixture
    {
        protected WebApplicationFactory<Startup> WebAppFactory { get; init; }
        public Fixture Fixture { get; init; }
        public HttpClient HttpClient { get; init; }
    
        private const int AccountId = 12345;
        private const int UserId = 5432;
    
        protected WebApplicationFactory<Startup> GetWebApplicationFactory()
        {
            var authenticationResultFake = AuthenticateResultFake.WithAuthenticatedRevealUser(AccountId, UserId);
    
            var factory = new ApiWebApplicationFactory(authenticationResultFake)
                .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
                {
                    builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
                    {
                        SetServices(services);
    
                        services.ReplaceSingleton<ILoggerFactory>(NullLoggerFactory.Instance);
                        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().CreateLogger();
                    });
                });
            factory.Server.PreserveExecutionContext = true; // see logger issue https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues/1083
            return factory;
        }

}

Full Exception -
 Failed VideoCamera.Api.Tests.Unit.Controllers.UserCamerasControllerTests.GetControlUnitsGroupedByVehicleTests.ControlUnitsByAccountId_ShouldReturnBadRequestForInvalidOffset [1 ms]
  Error Message:
   System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Unable to build IHost) (The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: RevealWebApplicationFixture revealWebApplicationFixture)
---- System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to build IHost
---- The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: RevealWebApplicationFixture revealWebApplicationFixture
  Stack Trace:
  
----- Inner Stack Trace #1 (System.InvalidOperationException) -----
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver.HostingListener.CreateHost()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<ResolveHostFactory>b__0(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.DeferredHostBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.DelegatedWebApplicationFactory.CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.ConfigureHostBuilder(IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.EnsureServer()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.get_Server()
   at VideoCamera.Api.Tests.Unit.Setup.WebApplicationFixture.GetWebApplicationFactory() in /vzc/bamboo/build-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/RVEMU-VIDCAMA552-JOB1/_src/VideoCamera.Api.Tests.Unit/Setup/WebApplicationFixture.cs:line 37
   at VideoCamera.Api.Tests.Unit.Setup.RevealWebApplicationFixture..ctor() in /vzc/bamboo/build-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/RVEMU-VIDCAMA552-JOB1/_src/VideoCamera.Api.Tests.Unit/Setup/RevealWebApplicationFixture.cs:line 33
----- Inner Stack Trace #2 (Xunit.Sdk.TestClassException) -----

Can someone please help me in fixing this?

Can you add the full exception text to your question

@stuartd, I have updated the full exception
